# Having the same PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

This problem took me long enough that I find it much of a relief taking any help to proceed further,

Show that these two relations between $x$, $y$ & $z$ have the same PDE:

1)     $z = a x^3 + by^3$

2) $z = ax^3 +bx^2y+cxy^2+\frac{dy^4}{x}$

I tried to differentiate w.r.t $x$ and then w.r.t $y$, and mixing partials as well, but that seems quite frustrating and hopeless, I wanna know is there any everywhere-accepted procedure, in which one can exhibit two (or more) equations have the same partial differential equation? If not, in this case, what can we do about it? What did you find out about like-wise problems, in your own experiences, and what do you suggest
? Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you supposed to know a priori the PDE? Or are you supposed to find a PDE which has both $1$ and $2$ as solutions?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial^{5} z}{\partial y^{5}} = 0$$ ?

Comment: Hmm, Any detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a standard procedure to solve this kind of problem. In order to find the pde **one** function fulfills, the idea is eliminate the constants ($a,b,c,d$ in this case). I've managed to find that $xz_x+yz_y=3z$ has as solution the first equation. It's the case it is satisfied by the second too.

$z=ax^3+by^3$

$z_x=3ax^2$ and $z_y=3by^2$

$a=z_x/(3x^2)$ and $b=z_y/(3y^2)$

$z=xz_x/3+yz_y/3$

$xz_x+yz_y=3z$

This equation has as general solution $z=x^3f(y/x)$

With $f(u)=a+bu^3$ we get the first solution.

With $f(u)=a+bu+cu^2+du^4$ we get the second.

**Added**

Both functions are homogeneous of degree three and, by virtue of [Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html), [they satisfy the same pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2260272/362604). So, the answer about a procedure to exhibit some functions are solution of the same pde has a partial answer, in positive for this special case.

Comment: Thx, you got it!

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar, there are some details worth to know. The functions are homogeneous. Check the addition to the answer :)